# Webview - Android App - Test to See if in Android App rather than Android Chrome

Tags: android, webview

I want a javascript test that tests whether I am in a Webview on an Android App, rather than just be running in Google Chrome on an Android phone.

Unfortunately this returns true in a Webview in an Android App and also when called from Chrome on an Android phone.

```
var g_IsAndroid = /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

I need something that only returns true when in a Webview when inside an Android App.

Any ideas?